# Azure media services php sdk error

Tags: php, azure, azure-media-services

I have an issue with azure media service php sdk.I  am trying to run index.php on my localhost but getting the following errors: Do not know what went wrong. 
i have attached the snapshot of error i am getting ,please take a look
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buCXK.png)

Comment: Can you please copy error and stack trace to question to make it searchable.

Comment: name=Encoded Mezzanine Azure-Video.wmv id=nb:cid:UUID:b7c5fb09-bf05-4282-aacd-26cf9c32024d 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Utilities::generateCryptoKey() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/azure_media/index.php:193 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/azure_media/index.php(77): createCommonTypeContentKey(Object(WindowsAzure\MediaServices\MediaServicesRestProxy), Object(WindowsAzure\MediaServices\Models\Asset)) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/azure_media/index.php on line 193

Comment: @TojoAlex Could you share some code using Azure Media Services SDK for PHP to help analyzing the issue?

Comment: @TojoAlex, please confirm that you are using the latest PHP SDK for Media Services - look for version 0.5.7 of the Microsoft/WindowsAzure package at https://packagist.org/packages/microsoft/windowsazure#v0.5.7